# Error in running 'git apply'

Tags: git

Can you please tell me how can I resolve the 'patch does not apply' error when I try to
'git apply-patch'?

```
$ git apply 0001-my.patch
error: patch failed:test.xml:114
error: text.xml: patch does not apply
```

I do have 'test.xml' in my local directory. And when I do 'git status', it shows I don't have local changes.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 12):

You can try a:

```
git am -3
```

> When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge ([`git am` doc](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html))

---

[qneill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468252/qneill) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842926/error-in-running-git-apply/1842964#comment22200507_1842964) that [`git apply` now have a `--3way` option](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v4-00-19-quot-git-apply-3way-quot-td7562763.html):

> you can now apply your patches without having to reduce context.
>   As it will leave the conflicted halves in the index and let you manually resolve conflicts in the working tree, "`--3way`" implies "`--index`", and cannot be used with "`--cached`" or "`--reject`".

You can see it in the [git1.7.12 release note](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.12.txt) (August 2012, a bit less than 3 years after the original question)

> "`git apply`" learned to wiggle the base version and perform three-way merge when a patch does not exactly apply to the version you have.

Comment: It looks like git-apply has a --3way option now as of 1.7.11.1 (see http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v4-00-19-quot-git-apply-3way-quot-td7562763.html)

Comment: @qneill good point. I have edited the answer to reflect that new feature.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the patch has information about what should be change to what. If the first what doesn't match file contents, the patch doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may also want to rebase with main or origin

```
git rebase origin
```

Just to make sure you are on the same track with latest changes before you will start applying patches from other guys.