# rebasing git branches that were rewritten since branching

Tags: git-rebase, git-reset

I have a git repository and two branches `master` and `st` (branched from `master`). I want to rebase `st` onto `master`. However, `master` has been massively rewritten by somebody else, to be frank I'm not sure why, but we were prompted to `fetch` the new `master` and `reset --hard` our private branches to it.

If I try `git-rebase` the listing of non-trivially conflicted files that need manual merges span over two screen pages.
I know that the actual changes are not that much. For one, the `st` branch only touched a handful of files (not more than ten, I'd guess).

Besides rebasing I tried to create a patch and apply it, but there are some conflicts as well, which I have no clue how to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be mind-bogglingly easy, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842926/error-in-running-git-apply/1842964#1842964), you can simply do

```
git am -3 changes.patch
```

if `changes.patch` is the full patch file.